# Sorting many to many in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have three tables: `Items`, `Category` and the junction table `CategoryItems`. Items and Category have a many to many relationship.

CategoryItems have three columns: `Category_Id`, `Item_Id` and `Position`.

How do i use `Position` to sort my items with Entity Framework?

I am using this model builder:

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Category>()
.HasMany(c => c.Items)
.WithMany();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this for the loading of a categories items:

```
 public IEnumerable<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            using (var context = new CatalogueContext())
            {
                var ids = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT Item_Id FROM CategoryItems WHERE Category_Id = " +
                                                         this.Id + " ORDER BY Position");
                foreach (int id in ids)
                    yield return context.Items.Find(id);

            }
        }
    }
```

And then using an SQL-query to change the position.

Answer (score 4):

EF doesn't support mapping many-to-many relationships if your junction table (`CategoryItems`) has additional columns over the foreign keys for each end of the relationship (in this case, `Position`). You will need to create another type (e.g. `CategoryItem`) and configure your mappings as two one-to-many relationships to this type.

In this case, both your `Category` and `Item` types will have (e.g.) `CategoryItem` collections, and the `CategoryItem` type will have a `Category` and `Item` property.

Therefore, to get the list of items for a category ordered by position, you would do something like:

```
var category = context.Categories.Find(categoryId);
var orderedItems = 
    category.CategoryItems.OrderBy(ci => ci.Position).Select(ci => ci.Item);
```

You'll probably want to choose a better name than `CategoryItem`, as although this is a good name to describe a junction table purely to model a many-to-many relationship, in your case it is actually an entity in itself.